# Trigger Build automatically in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to trigger a build definition (automatically) from a work item transition?
How can I achieve this in TFS 2018?

Comment: Why would you want to build when a work item changes as opposed to when the **repository** changes?

Comment: When you say "Repository changes" you made when I make a commit for example? Like Continuous Integration?

Comment: Yes. The state of work items shouldn't control your build process, the state of the repository should. A build can (and will) encompass the work done (i.e. commits) to complete **many** work items.

Answer (score -1):

There is not any built-in trigger to handle this at present.

> However, as a workaround, you could **use web hook to trigger builds
>   when work item states are changes**.
>
> #### Prerequisites as below:
>
> - Build related to work item states.
> - Your own website to receive message from VSTS web hook and send request to build related builds.
> - Config a web hook in VSTS.
>
> #### Detail steps as below:
>
> 1. **Create builds related to work item states** as `Ready to build`, `Ready to deployment` etc.
> 2. **Configure a service hook:**
>
>    In the team project -> Services Hooks -> Create subscription -> Web
>      Hooks -> Next -> select **Work item updated** as trigger on this type
>      of event -> filter Field as **State** -> Next -> input your website’s
>      URL -> Test -> make sure it can work successful -> Finish.
> 3. **Develop your own website with below functions:**
>
>    - Check the current state of the work item updated. You can [get a work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#get-a-work-item) information by REST API, and the check the value for
>        `System.State`.
>    - Trigger related build to queue. According to the value of `System.State`, queue different builds. Such as if `System.State` is
>        `Ready to build`, then [queue the build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build) for this state.

More details take a look at this similar question: [Trigger builds based on TFS workitem information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469792/trigger-builds-based-on-tfs-workitem-information)

Besides, you could also file a feature request in Develop Community site. Our PM will kindly review your suggestion

[image]

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, vote to close it as a duplicate instead of posting a redundant answer.