# How to trigger an event in VSTS when there is a state change

Tags: email, azure-devops, workitem

I am looking to create a trigger (ideally a json payload must be sent to a server) when an User Story is changed to closed/resolved state.

I am following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

How can I achieve this with Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to trigger an event in VSTS when there is a state change

First, Azure Devops has capabilities to set up email notifications for the work Item. Check this the document [Manage your notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/howto-manage-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

For you requirement, you could add a new subscription with following settings:

[image]

Then, if any User Story is changed to `closed/resolved` state, you will receive a e-mail about it.

**Besides**, if the trigger event is more than just a e-mail notification, like build. You could configure a service hook to send request to build related builds:

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469792/trigger-builds-based-on-tfs-workitem-information) for the details.

Hope this helps.